# Where is "PodMetrics" kind defined?

Tags: kubernetes

I've been studying k8s' API aggregation layer and extension api server. As I understand it, it is the same thing to extend the API of k8s API server similar to CRD, but the backend implementation is different. CRD was to provide a schema to store a new object(Resource) in ETCD and add CRUD for the added resource to the API server. However, in the case of API aggregation, I understood it as extending the API of the K8S API server by operating the K8S API server as a kind of proxy, and letting the actual business logic be handled by a custom extension API server.

The metrics server is a prime example, and I used it a lot. However, when I queried pod metrics through this metrics server, I was able to check the metrics of the pod through a kind of resource called PodMetrics. In the k8s docs, there was an example of checking through `curl` or `kubectl get -raw`, but it was also possible to check through `kubectl get podmetrics`. I also checked the k8s yaml manifest of the metrics server on Github, but couldn't find a file defining a PodMetrics resource anywhere. Where did this PodMetrics resource come from?

Comment: You can run commands like **kubectl top** [doc](https://www.mankier.com/1/kubectl-top-pod) & **kubectl describe**, shows metrics for a given pod. Which is based on the reports from cAdvisor, which gather real pods resource consumption. Run kubectl top inside the pod, run it on the host system because the pod is using the kernel of the host system. See [Resource metrics](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kubernetes-performance-metrics/#resource-metrics) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The types definitions for the Metrics API are defined in [`kubernetes/metrics`](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics). Within `kubernetes/metrics`, the `PodMetrics` struct is defined in [`/pkg/apis/metrics/types.go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/c7f35d74b376851440581d863edf38bc5f731f9d/pkg/apis/metrics/types.go#L66-L80).

```golang
type PodMetrics struct {
    metav1.TypeMeta
    // Standard object's metadata.
    // More info: https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#metadata
    // +optional
    metav1.ObjectMeta

    // The following fields define time interval from which metrics were
    // collected from the interval [Timestamp-Window, Timestamp].
    Timestamp metav1.Time
    Window    metav1.Duration

    // Metrics for all containers are collected within the same time window.
    Containers []ContainerMetrics
}
```

Any Go implementation of the Metrics API such as `metrics-server` should [require](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/d7f6d5b64fcd535c63efbfc573da86767997286d/go.mod#L20) `k8s.io/metrics`.

As to how the `PodMetrics` kind gets added to the Kubernetes API, there is an `Install` function that [registers](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/c7f35d74b376851440581d863edf38bc5f731f9d/pkg/apis/metrics/install/install.go#L30) the API group and resource types. If you follow that function, you'll find `PodMetrics` being [added](https://github.com/kubernetes/metrics/blob/c7f35d74b376851440581d863edf38bc5f731f9d/pkg/apis/metrics/register.go#L51) to the [scheme](https://github.com/kubernetes/apimachinery/blob/fa98d6eaedb4caccd69fc07d90bbb6a1e551f00f/pkg/runtime/scheme.go#L31-L45).

```golang
scheme.AddKnownTypes(SchemeGroupVersion,
    &NodeMetrics{},
    &NodeMetricsList{},
    &PodMetrics{},
    &PodMetricsList{},
)
```